# Построение пути

Tags: javascript

На карте имеется метка, созданная через var. К этом метке прикрчен кастомный балун. При нажатии на метку этот балун появляется. Внутри балуна есть поле ввода, в которое требуется ввести адрес и кнопка, при нажатии на которую нужно построить маршрут от точки, к которой привязан балун, до точки, которая соответствует адресу, введенному в поле инпута. Я не могу понять, как построить этот маршрут.

Comment: Пожалуйста разверните ваш вопрос, какие точки ? куда и откуда строиться маршрут что за маршрут? чем строиться? как? зачем?
ничего же не понятно..

Comment: Смотрите. Есть точка, добавленная на карту. При нажатии на эту точку появляется балун, в котором есть поле ввода адреса и кнопка "Go". Я не понимаю как после введения адреса и нажатия на кнопку "Go" сразу построить маршрут к введенном адресу.

Comment: У вас точка имеет какие-то координаты? В чем проблема определять точку адреса и к ней вести маршрут?